# Bash remembers wrong path to an executable that was moved/deleted

Tags: bash, path, which

When I do

```
which pip3
```

I get

```
/usr/local/bin/pip3
```

but when I try to execute `pip3` I get an error as follows:

```
bash: /usr/bin/pip3: No such file or directory
```

This is because I recently deleted that file. Now `which` command points to another version of `pip3` that is located in `/usr/local/bin` but the shell still remembers the wrong path. How do I make it forget about that path?

The `which` manual says

```
which returns the pathnames of the files (or links) which would be executed in the current environment, had its arguments been given as commands in
       a strictly POSIX-conformant shell.  It does this by searching the PATH for executable files matching the names of the arguments. It does not follow
       symbolic links.
```

Both `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/bin` are in my `PATH` variable, and `/usr/local/bin/pip3` is not a symbolic link, it's an executable. So why doesn't it execute?

Comment: What is the content of `/usr/local/bin/pip3`?

Comment: Had you previously run `pip3` in that shell while it was in `/usr/bin` and then moved it?

Comment: What do you see if you run `hash -t pip3`?

Comment: @Eric Renouf Yes,  I had 2 versions of `pip3` and deleted one of them. I edited the question.

Comment: if you do a "echo $PATH" you'll see /usr/bin/ and /usr/local/bin. I'd assume that the order is relevant. As a quick fix. just could make a symbolic link and you're good to go: ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip3

Comment: @Eric Renouf `hash -t pip3` prints `/usr/bin/pip3`

Comment: Unless you have a very good reason, you should always use `type` eather than `which`. `type` is built into a posix shell and tells you what a shell will do, rather than `which` which tries to guess what the shell will do.

Comment: @spiderface [Why does `type which` say that `which is hashed`?](http://askubuntu.com/q/446580/253474)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

When you run a command in `bash` it will remember the location of that executable so it doesn't have to search the `PATH` again each time.  So if you run the executable, then change the location, `bash` will still try to use the old location.  You should be able to confirm this with `hash -t pip3` which will show the old location.

If you run `hash -d pip3` it will tell bash to forget the old location and should find the new one next time you try.

Comment: Or `hash -r` to clear the whole table.

Comment: Yes, that worked. I think I'll change the title of the question because it has nothing to do with `which`.

Comment: Where can I read the usage of the `hash` command? My system only has a very unhelpful manpage that is identical to this one: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/hash.3.html

Comment: @spiderface for most bash features it's easier to use `help` instead of man, so here `help hash`

Comment: @spiderface `type hash` will tell you that it's a shell builtin, so it doesn't have its own man page. Instead, use `help hash` or look up `hash` in bash's man page.

Comment: Or, if you really want to use `man`...since `hash` is a `bash` builtin, you would want `man bash` to find it.  But what the man page says is essentially what `help hash` to bash says.

Comment: This will also reset the PATH cache and IMO is easier to remember:  `PATH=$PATH`

Comment: Since bash is calling hash -t pip3 underneath, why doesn't it call hash -d pip3 automatically once it discovers the file is not there?  Or at least issue a warning and suggestion to run "hash -d pip3"?

Comment: I've tried hash -d <file> and hash -r, AND IT *STILL* USES THE WRONG PATH!  (Damn I hate Linux!)

Comment: @UserX If you run `hash -t <name>` do you see an entry there?  That should show you where `bash` is expecting that name to be found on disk.  What is the symptom of "wrong path" for you?

Answer (score 0):

When changing the location of an executable (by moving it or making a new version of an executable available in a different location), use `hash -d NAME` to force bash to look for it again in PATH. However, if NAME is not in the cache, this will error, so as part of your scripts, use something like this:

```
if hash -t $NAME >& /dev/null; then 
  hash -d $NAME
fi
```